# How to replace only single backslash in java json string

Tags: java, json, string, web-services

I am getting data from the wcf webservice as :

```
"[{\"ID\":51,\"Text\":\"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!\"}]"
```

I am recieving this data in my android app and I am using these function to remove backslash and start-end double quote and its working fine for me:

```
   line = reader.readLine();
                String jsonFormattedString = line.replaceAll("\\\\", "");//remove backslashes
                jsonFormattedString= jsonFormattedString.substring(1, jsonFormattedString.length()-1) ;//remove start and end double quotes
```

Now the problem is that I am getting new data  where there are double quotes within strings and when I remove back slashes from the above two functions I get error as string ends where double quote is found and characters after double quotes are treated as illegal characters. I am recieving data like this:

```
"[{\"ID\":9617,\"Text\":\"1 1\/4\\\" PVC\/GI CLAMPS\"}]"
```

Here if you look into this string after 1/4 there is a double quote(") which represents inches but when I use above function to replace backslash I get error as this double quote is treated as end of the string.Please help.

I am using this method to get json data from the string.

```
   JSONArray j = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);
                JSONObject jsonmain = j.getJSONObject(0);

                int lengthJsonArr = j.length();

                for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {

                    jsonmain = j.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("Jsonnnnn----",jsonmain.getString("Text"));
                    Itm=new CItem(jsonmain.getString("ID"),jsonmain.getString("Text"));
                    lstItm.add(Itm);


                }
```

Comment: Which library are you using for parsing JSON?

Comment: please see the edit in question.Now I am showing how I  am getting json data from the string.

Comment: Is this json ("[{\"ID\":9617,\"Text\":\"1 1\/4\\\" PVC\/GI CLAMPS\"}]") coming from your webservice ? Because it seems not a valid String ! Otherwise please share the first incoming String before your replace.

Comment: @Sercan yes its json string as it automatically put backslashes in it I dont know why So for removing these back slashes I needed to use those functions.

Comment: It puts backslashes to escape double quotes in String, it's natural. But when you copy your this String and put it into a variable in Eclipse, you can see it's not a valid String, btw you don't have to replace backslashes, json reader will read it anyway

Comment: Now removed replace statement with   String jsonFormattedString = line; but now I am getting this exception :  05-15 10:36:52.173    2578-2597/kanix.highrise.com.highrise D/ERRROR--->﹕ Expected literal value at character 2 of [{\"ID\":51,\"Text\":\"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!\"},{\"ID\":58,\"Text\":\"01 Contracting Test Project\"} ]